# Call Custom Function on Form Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a function to swap data-attribute and action in a form:

```
$(function() {
    function SwapAction() {
        var dataAttr = $('.review-form').data();
        $('.review-form')[0].action = dataAttr.action;
    }
});
```

I want to do this upon submission of the form if the form passes validation checks. The validation JS looks like so:

```
var submitcount7303 = 0;

function checkWholeForm7303(theForm) {
  var why = "";
  if (theForm.FirstName) why += isEmpty(theForm.FirstName.value, "First Name");
  if (theForm.LastName) why += isEmpty(theForm.LastName.value, "Last Name");
  if (theForm.EmailAddress) why += checkEmail(theForm.EmailAddress.value);
  if (why != "") {
    alert(why);
    return false;
  }
  if (submitcount7303 == 0) {
    submitcount7303++;
    SwapAction(); //Calling Function 
    theForm.submit();
    return false;
  } else {
    alert("Form submission is in progress.");
    return false;
  }
}
```

The form doesn't submit and I receive an error:

```
Reference Error: SwapAction is not defined.
```

Here is the form HTML with the action:

```
<form action="" data-action="/FormProcessv2.aspx?WebFormID=89926&amp;OID={module_oid}&amp;OTYPE={module_otype}&amp;EID={module_eid}&amp;CID={module_cid}" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return checkWholeForm7303(this)" method="post" name="catwebformform7303" class="review-form custom">
```

I assume I am overlooking something simple. If I remove `SwapAction();` and remove the `data-action` and set the form back to default it works without a problem.

How do I fix the error and implement my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is not in scope, it's within the scope of the wrapping DOM ready function, so remove that :

```
function SwapAction() {
    var dataAttr = $('.review-form').data();
    $('.review-form')[0].action = dataAttr.action;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You define `SwapAction()` in the callback function of document ready, that's a different scope, so you can't access it in global scope.

Answer (score 1):

`SwapAction()` is out of scope here.

If you want to use your first approach:

```
$(function() {
SwapAction = function {
    var dataAttr = $('.review-form').data();
    $('.review-form')[0].action = dataAttr.action;
}
});
```

And then you can call it as you are calling in your current code.